# How do you concatenate an integer onto the end of an object Name in C++

Tags: c++, qt

So I am building a program to calculate matrix multiplication to teach myself c++ and Qt. So I have some text edit windows labled with integers such as matrixPosA11, matrixPosA12, MatrixPosA13. How do I concatenate an integer onto the string so I can use a loop to cycle through them from the general form matrixPosAxx to rerieve their values. Thanks.

Comment: Typically, this means that you probably wanted an array in the first place.

Comment: In C and C++, the names of variables are compile-time only, once the machine code is generated, the names of variables are no longer used [they may still exist for debug purposes, but the code does not "know" that]

Comment: @MatsPetersson there are partial ways to hack it. in which you can use `type_info::name` on some compilers and the `#define varname(x) #x` macro

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to concatenate numbers with text:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
char letter = 'A';
int number = 11;
oss << "matrixPos" << letter << number;
std::string label = oss.str(); // extract string
```

You'll then need to find a Qt function to find the label widget with that name....

Another option is [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
#include <string>

std::string label = std::string("matrixPos") + letter +
                    std::to_string(number);
```

(In C++, you need to make one of the two left-most values in a `string` concatenation a `string` object, to ensure the `string` concatenation functions are used, which is why `std::string("matrixPos")` has to be used instead of simply `"matrixPos"`.  Otherwise, `"matrixPos" + letter` would be evaluated by taking a *pointer* to the `m` in `"matrixPos"` and advancing it by `letter` (the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code of the letter) bytes.

---

It's generally more maintainable to find some manner of grid or table widget that lets you access cells at specific coordinates: then two integers can specify which cell to retrieve or update, and you can more easily use a two-dimensional array in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_string` (C++11).

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int age = 71;
  std::cout << "You are " << std::to_string(age) << " old." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QString::number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-2):

```
QString baseStr = QLatin1String(“matrixPos1”);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    const QString objectName = baseStr + QString::number(i+1);
    ...
}
```